# SoftLayer API Exception when filtering SoftLayer_Product_Package categories

Tags: filter, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

According to XSD file, `SoftLayer_Product_PackageObjectFilter` receive a `categories` parameter that is a `tns:SoftLayer_Product_Item_CategoryObjectFilter`.

`SoftLayer_Product_Item_CategoryObjectFilter` accepts `categoryCode` that is a `SoftLayer_Utility_ObjectFilter_Operation`, so a filter to get only categories with categoryCode 'guest_disk0' would be:

```
object_filter = {
  'categories': {
    'categoryCode': {
      'operation': 'guest_disk0'
    }
  }
}
```

When I call with this filter on header, I'm receiving `SoftLayer_Exception_Public`

Here is my SOAP request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="http://api.service.softlayer.com/soap/v3.1/" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Header>
    <authenticate>
      <username>USER</username>
      <apiKey>KEY</apiKey>
    </authenticate>
    <tns:SoftLayer_Product_PackageObjectFilter>
      <categories>
        <categoryCode>
          <operation>guest_disk0</operation>
        </categoryCode>
      </categories>
    </tns:SoftLayer_Product_PackageObjectFilter>
    <tns:SoftLayer_ObjectMask>
      <mask>mask[categoryCode,name]</mask>
    </tns:SoftLayer_ObjectMask>
    <SoftLayer_Product_PackageInitParameters>
      <id>46</id>
    </SoftLayer_Product_PackageInitParameters>
  </env:Header>
  <env:Body>
    <tns:getCategories></tns:getCategories>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Following the exact same idea, but filtering `activeRamItems` for `keyName` we can perfectly use the filter

```
object_filter = {
  'activeRamItems': {
    'keyName': {
      'operation': 'RAM_12_GB'
    }
  }
}
```

The SOAP request is exact the same used for categories, just changing the filter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="http://api.service.softlayer.com/soap/v3.1/" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Header>
    <authenticate>
      <username>USER</username>
      <apiKey>KEY</apiKey>
    </authenticate>
    <tns:SoftLayer_Product_PackageObjectFilter>
      <activeRamItems>
        <keyName>
          <operation>RAM_12_GB</operation>
        </keyName>
      </activeRamItems>
    </tns:SoftLayer_Product_PackageObjectFilter>
    <tns:SoftLayer_ObjectMask>
      <mask>mask[id,keyName]</mask>
    </tns:SoftLayer_ObjectMask>
    <SoftLayer_Product_PackageInitParameters>
      <id>46</id>
    </SoftLayer_Product_PackageInitParameters>
  </env:Header>
  <env:Body>
    <tns:getActiveRamItems></tns:getActiveRamItems>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I do **REALLY** believe this is an API error, but as the SoftLayer procedure is open a question on stack overflow for any API related issues, I'm opening here

Comment: Yep it is an issue, but if you are looking to get the prices of the items for a package I suggest you to use the getItems or getItemPrices methods, those are the methods used by the softlayer's portal.

Comment: hi Nelson, thank you for your comment... `getItems` is exactly what I was looking for, thank you for your information, just a question, `getItems` only returns SAN "second disk" category, not third, fourth and fifth, how should I proceed? thank you!

Comment: that depends on the price try adding this object mask: objectMask=mask[prices[categories]] , you will see that a price is valid for second, thrid, etc disk. regards

Comment: I just noticed that information is also in the item using this mask: mask[categories]

Comment: makes sense!! the same item price is used for some categories, now I got the information I was looking for! thank you Nelson!